# command at that run from cmd isnot working

Tags: windows, cmd, at-job

I run the following AT command in windows CMD: **at 8:52 "start calc"** [image: screen capture of the CMD windows commands.]it is scheduled and can be seen in the list when running "at" but when reached the time it is not executed as accepted and when running "at" again it is deleted from the list ???
What is the reason and how to fix it ?

See the screen capture of the CMD windows commands.

Comment: Is there an error message in the task scheduler? Do you see something in event logs?

Comment: There's no "start.exe" command. That's an internal command of the CMD shell. Just run "calc.exe".

Comment: That said, the AT service is deprecated in Windows 8+, and by default the corresponding [`NetSchedule*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmat/) functions fail with `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. Use the Task Scheduler's "schtasks.exe" command instead.

Comment: To confirm what @eryksun says, just type `at` (in cmd or powershell if you want).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the suggestions I used schtasks.exe that works on win 8 and 7:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn run_calc /st 17:07 /tr calc.exe
```